# Blademail damage return by owned or summoned units

Tags: dota-2, dota

For example lycan. 
His summoned wolves attack a target with active blademail,
Who will have the impact of the return damage, Lycan or the wolves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wolves most likely. Blademail returns damage to an attacking unit and summoned units/illusions are considered separate entities from their summoner (unless specified otherwise in some future skill).

Answer (score 5):

Be aware that wards placed by Rhasta's ult or Venomancer's ability will return the damage to the summoner instead of the wards. Killing them this way is possible, even at a great distance (this worked in DotA, not sure about DotA 2)